# How do I insert a data extension variable immediately after an "="?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, parsing

So within my email, I can call a data extension field:

%%User_Type%%

When previewed, this displays as either "Free" or "Premium" depending on the user.

For data tracking via google analytics, I want a link in my email to pass this information via URL argument:

[www.mysite.com/?usertype=%%User_Type%%](http://www.mysite.com/?usertype=%%User_Type%%)

However, this throws up a parsing error, wherein the system doesn't recognize the first "%%"

If I use THIS:

[www.mysite.com/?usertype=](http://www.mysite.com/?usertype=) %%User_Type%%

It works fine, except the output is "www.mystie.com/?usertype= Premium"

Note the space between the = and the Premium.  This breaks the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using [AttributeValue](https://ampscript.guide/attributevalue), so if `User_Type` doesn't exist in the send context, your email will still compile:

```ampscript
%%[

set @varName = AttributeValue("User_Type")
set @varName = trim(@varName)

]%%
<a href="https://www.mysite.com/?usertype=%%=v(@varName)=%%">link<a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a workaround.

I declare the variable as %%[Set @varName = User_Type]%%

Then later I'm able to do this call, and it parses correctly:

[www.mysite.com/?usertype=%%=v(@varName)=%%](http://www.mysite.com/?usertype=%%=v(@varName)=%%)